# Merge multiple admin accounts into 1 admin account on Windws 10

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, merge

I have created 3 separate profiles for work / work / pleasure in Windows 10.

I have since ran into VPN issues with users logged in still and other administrative permission issues and its becoming a hassle.

I don't need to move any files, however I'd like to combine all 3 user preferences into 1 account (basically programs that were installed on 1 account are not showing on the other account i'd like to use them on), restart and have everything in 1, separating minor issues after the fact.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is links in the Start Menu, that can be done pretty easily: just copy files from `C:\Users\%ACCOUNT1_USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` to `C:\Users\%ACCOUNT2_USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`